# Jquery function partialy executes / Uncaught Typeerror: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, web, typeerror

I am trying to create part of a simple forum that allows for **pairing of a shoe size with respective quantity**.

This information will eventually be passed to a database. As it stands I have a jquery script that partially works. I can enter a size, and then add that size to a list. The script stops here. my console tells me that I have an **uncaught type error.**

I have no idea what this means or what I am to do. I am learning this as I go so please be kind as I am trying.

**The code is as follows**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<fieldset>
    <legend>ShoeSize</legend>
    Add Size: <input type="text" name="newSize" id="newSize"/>
    <input type="button" value="add" id="addbutton"/>
    <br/>
    Available Sizes: <select name="availableSizes" id="availableSizes" size="1"></select>
    Quantity of Available Size: <input type="text" name="quantOfSize" id="quantOfSize"/>
    <input type="button" value="set" id="setQuant"/>
  </fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addbutton').click(function(){
        var size = $('#newSize').val();
        var sizelist = $('#availableSizes');
        var sizeOption = $('<option value="'+ size +'">'+ size +'</option>');

        sizelist.append(sizeOption);
        size.val('');
        size.reset();
    });
    $('#setQuant').click(function() {
        var quantity = $('#quantOfSize').val();
        if (quantity == " ") {
            alert('Invalid quantity set');
        } else{
            alert('We have ' + quantity +' shoes of '+ 'size '+ size);
        };
    })
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have yet to test the set quantity button. So if it works for you all let me know and if it doesn't then show me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had 2 problems in your code

a)

```
var size = $('#newSize').val();
size.val('');
```

this causes an exception because once you do '.val' you no longer have a reference to the object but to its value, so the solution is to use `$('#newSize').val('')` or get the `$('#newSize')` into a variable `var size = $('#newSize')` - and then manipulate it.

b)

You're referencing 'size' in your second click handler but your initial variable is out of scope, so you need to created it again, but this time get it from the selected drop-down :-)

I've created a JSFiddle with the full working code for you: http://jsfiddle.net/EdsonF/QM9Gs/

Hope it helps

Edson

Comment: Thanks man, learned a lot in just a few seconds. As to everyone who contributed thank you for your time as well.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this and also remove `reset()` function because it belong to form not input

```
    var size = $('#newSize');
    var sizelist = $('#availableSizes');
    var sizeOption = $('<option value="'+ size +'">'+ size.val() +'</option>');
    sizelist.append(sizeOption);
    size.val('');
```

Comment: My thinking was that because the input box was a form object it would work. But now I see that it's not a form object without the form tag...right?